# Scala implicit conversions between functional objects?

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to re-bind some of the functions in `scala.math` to take and return `Float` objects rather than `Double` objects so that I can bind them to a function registrar that works with functions that take and return `Float` objects. I've tried this rule:

```
implicit def doubleFunc2floatFunc[T <: { def apply(x:Double):Double }] (func:T) = func(_:Float).floatValue
```

and it doesn't work. The compiler complains that my functions are `(Double)=>Float` rather than `(Float)=>Float`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**: the code I am using this in is as follows:

```
package org.nathanmoos.magnificalc.exprtreelib.functions

import org.nathanmoos.magnificalc.exprtreelib.Functions
import scala.math._


object InternalFunctions
{
    implicit def float2double(x:Float) = x.doubleValue
    // need an implicit def doubleFunc2floatFunc
    implicit def double2float(x:Double) = x.floatValue
    def csc(x:Float):Float = 1f/sin(x)
    def sec(x:Float):Float = 1f/cos(x)
    def cot(x:Float):Float = 1f/tan(x)

    def registerAll() = {
        Functions.register("ln", log _)
        Functions.register("log", log10 _)
        Functions.register("sqrt", sqrt _)
        Functions.register("sin", sin _)
        Functions.register("cos", cos _)
        Functions.register("tan", tan _)
        Functions.register("csc", csc _)
        Functions.register("sec", sec _)
        Functions.register("cot", cot _)
        Functions.register("sinh", sinh _)
        Functions.register("cosh", cosh _)
        Functions.register("tanh", tanh _)
        Functions.register("acos", acos _)
        Functions.register("asin", asin _)
        Functions.register("atan", atan _)
    }
}
```

`Functions.register` takes a `String` for the function's name and a function-object to associate it with.

Comment: Please show how you are using the code as well.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral: Done.

Comment: What's the type signature of `Functions.register`? I assume the error happens on calls to it, right?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, the error occurs on calls to it. `Functions.register` is defined as follows: `def register(name:String, func:(Float)=>Float)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is going on, but it first checks for the return type of the function, and then fails if it can't solve that. But if you *do* make it possible for it to fix the return type, then it proceeds to check the whole function.

So you can do it by creating two implicits:

```
implicit def doubleToFloat(d: Double): Float = d.toFloat
implicit def doubleFunc2floatFunc(df : Double => Float) : Float => Float = (f : Float) => df(f)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would it be better to use `Double` instead of `Float`? The app is a graphing calculator, and this system allows plugging in additional functions.

Comment: @Nathan Definitely. `Float` is a forgotten class in Java-land.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for structural types or type parameters here,

```
scala> implicit def doubleFunc2floatFunc(df : Double => Double) : Float => Float = (f : Float) => df(f).toFloat
doubleFunc2floatFunc: (df: (Double) => Double)(Float) => Float
```

Then in use,

```
scala> val f : Float => Float = scala.math.abs
f: (Float) => Float = <function1>

scala> f(-1.0)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double(-1.0)
 required: Float
   f(-1.0)
     ^

scala> f(-1.0f)
res1: Float = 1.0
```

Comment: Misleading. It doesn't actually work -- try it with `log`, which is not overloaded. It seemed to work here because `abs` has a `(Float)Float` version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the underlying issue (after we remove implicits which are already in predef, unnecessary structural types, and then limit ourselves to math functions which aren't overloaded) is a weird type inference interaction between weak conformance and eta expansion.  The parameter type Float conforms to the expected parameter type Double, and so the implicit conversion for the function type doesn't trigger; it kicks in for the result type, which is too late.  It has already decided the parameter type is Double.

```
scala> implicit def dd2ff(x: Double => Double): Float => Float = x => x
dd2ff: (x: (Double) => Double)(Float) => Float

scala> def dd(x: Double) = x
dd: (x: Double)Double

scala> val ff: Float => Float = (dd _)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Float
       val ff: Float => Float = (dd _)
                                 ^

scala> val x = dd _
x: (Double) => Double = <function1>

scala> val ff: Float => Float = x
ff: (Float) => Float = <function1>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why my two implicits make it work? Neither alone is enough.